# Are TFS 2010 (a.k.a. Microsoft ALM 2010) web services exposed\documented

Tags: synchronization, tfs-workitem

I'm trying to find up to date info on commuicating with TFS 2010 (now also refered to Microsoft ALM 2010, I believe).

This previous post [192579](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192579/tfs-webservice-documentation) from a Microsoft TFS team member states :
*The web services are not documented by Microsoft as it is not an officially supported route to talk to TFS. The officially supported route is to use their .NET API.*

But this was anwser was back from 2008, so I was wondering if this is still the case with 2010.  There is a post 2010 post that talks about using [powershell and the tfs web services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2010/01/12/tfs2010-invoking-tfs-web-services-using-powershell.aspx).

To give some context, I basically need to sync some workitems between TFS and another system.  So if anyone has some advice on that it would be appreciated!

emp

Answer (score 4):

Directly calling the web services in TFS 2010 is still a non-supported route.  If your need is to synchronize work items between TFS and some other system, I highly recommend you check out the [TFS Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/) project on CodePlex.

Comment: Agreed with Jeff.  The Work Item Webservices would be a lot more work than you might think to do what you wanted to do (sync workitems between TFS and another system).  The TFS integration Platform project on CodePlex is definately the way to go as that builds on top of the TFS work item object model and gives you a much nicer interface for doing exactly what you want to do.